# Combine Strings with Missing Value

Tags: r, data-manipulation

This is my sample data.

```
index <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
a <- c('a','b','c',NA,'D','e',NA,'g','h','i')
data <- data.frame(index,a)
```

What I would like to is create a new column name where only 'a' and 'b' stay. All others like 'c','d','e'...will be tagged as others, while NA stays as NA.

```
data$name = ifelse(!grepl('(a|b)',data$a),'others',data$name)
```

I tried to use the grepl function and it seems it is not working with data with missing values

Comment: `ifelse(!greplt('(a|b)', data$a) & !is.na(data$a), 'others', data$name)`

Comment: I received the error: replacement has length zero

Comment: `ifelse(!grepl('(a|b)', data$a) & !is.na(data$a), 'others', as.character(data$a))`

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```
data$res <- as.character(data$a)
data$res[! data$a %in% c("a","b") & !is.na(data$a)] <- "Other"
data
#    index    a   res
# 1      1    a     a
# 2      2    b     b
# 3      3    c Other
# 4      4 <NA>  <NA>
# 5      5    D Other
# 6      6    e Other
# 7      7 <NA>  <NA>
# 8      8    g Other
# 9      9    h Other
# 10    10    i Other
```

Note that the new column is of type `character` here.

Comment: Thanks. I need to tag c,d,e,f,h,i as 'others' while NA stays as NA

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and its `recode` function, you could do

```
data %>% mutate(name=recode(a, a="a", b="b", .default="other"))
#    index    a  name
# 1      1    a     a
# 2      2    b     b
# 3      3    c other
# 4      4 <NA>  <NA>
# 5      5    D other
# 6      6    e other
# 7      7 <NA>  <NA>
# 8      8    g other
# 9      9    h other
# 10    10    i other
```

With a more complicated match, you migth use `case_when` instead

```
data %>% mutate(name=case_when(
  is.na(a) ~ NA_character_, 
  a %in% c("a","b") ~ as.character(a), 
  TRUE ~ "other"))
```